# How does one use a function to compute the value of a member of a structure using values of other members in C?

Tags: c

I have created a struct in C with three members of type int.

I want to use a function to compute the value of the member C by adding the values a and b as shown in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct nums
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} number;

void add (number one);

int main (void)
{
  number start = {.c = 3, .b = 4};
  add (start);
  printf("the sum is %d \n", start.c);
  return (0);

}

void add (number one)
{
  one.c = one.a + one.b;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the value of c as 3 instead of 7. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you mean `start = {.a = 3, .b = 4};`, Instead you initialised `c` to 3.

Answer (score 3):

## Pass argument as a pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct nums
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} number;
void add (number *pOne);
int main (void)
{
  number start = {.a = 3, .b = 4, .c = 0};
  add (&start);
  printf("the sum is %d \n", start.c);
  return (0);

}
void add (number *pOne)
{
  pOne->c = pOne->a + pOne->b;
}
```

##### WHY POINTERS?

You pass the address of `start` as a pointer to `add` so that you can update `start` from within `add(...)`. Otherwise, `add` would update a copy of `start` stored on the stack that gets popped off on the return of `add`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So that we can update `start` from within `add(...)`. Otherwise, `add` would update a copy of `start` stored on the stack that gets popped off on the return of `add`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin When I saw your rep, I got the hint. Thanks for taking the time to give constructive feedback.

Comment: No worries -- always worth a helpful reminder to help improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in C, if you pass a variable to a function, first the value of the variable is copied and then the function receives it.

So `add` function modifies the copy, not original one.

If you want to modify the original one in another function, you should pass the address of a variable.

Addresses are also copied when passed, but it's not a problem because the destination isn't copied.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tagNumber {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} Number;

void add(Number* one) {
    one->c = one->a + one->b;
}

int main() {
    Number start = { .c=3, .b=4 };
    add(&start);
    printf("the sum is %d\n", start.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out in C everything is *pass-by-value*. When you pass the address of an object -- it is simply passed-by-value, but the address the pointer holds will the the address of the original from the calling function. You are correct that the value of the variable is copied, but the other half of the story is that function parameters are local to the function, so they are initialized with the value.